# Is colouring the edges of a cube the same as constructing a cube with matches?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, permutations

In the lecture on Polya's enumeration theorem, the professor did an example about the number of ways you could construct a cube with matches (every edge is associated with a direction). The argument hinges on the assumption that this problem is essentially the same as counting the different colourings of the cube, which he didn't justify.

However, is it really the same problem? I can see that in the colouring problem, what we are counting are different maps from edges to colours, where the group action is defined by composition. I can't see how the same argument can apply to the 'matches' case: the rotation won't change the colours, but it can change the directions (if we think of them as $0$ and $1$), however you map the directions to $0$'s and $1$'s.

Specifically, consider the cube

[image: cube]

And we decide arbitrarily that the directions $1 \rightarrow 4$ and $8 \rightarrow 1$ are mapped to colour red. This makes sense if the rotation axis is the line connecting the centres of the top and bottom faces, since $1 \rightarrow 4$ goes to $8 \rightarrow 1$.

However, if we rotate clockwise (viewed from top), using the line connecting $1$ and $2$ as axis, then $1 \rightarrow 4$ will become $1 \rightarrow 8$, changing the colour.

Comment: If there are just two colours then that's an obvious equivalence to two orientations. You can say direction 0 is red, direction 1 is blue, for example.

Comment: @NickG I elaborated on what I thought. Still I think there's no 'consistent' way of mapping colours to directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is the same problem, at least in general. Instead of a cube, consider just a square. There are six ways to $2$-colour the edges (all red, all blue, three red, three blue, two opposite edges of each, two adjacent edges of each). But there are only four ways to orient the edges, because flipping the square means that "all clockwise" and "all anticlockwise" are the same.

It may be that orienting the edges up to rotations is the same as colouring up to {rotations or swapping the colours}; I can't immediately see whether this is true or not.

[edit] The above is true, because the cube is bipartite. The right approach is to label the positions of vertices of the cube alternately A and B, and then say that an oriented edge from A to B corresponds to a red edge, and an edge oriented the other way corresponds to blue. Now rotating a given orientation of the cube will either leave all colours the same or swap all colours in this correspondence.